# Simplex Algorithm, determining Two Phase is required and choice of artificial variables

Tags: linear-programming, simplex, two-phase-simplex

Given the following system :

\begin{align*}
  \text{minimise } z = &2x_1 &+ 3x_2 &+ 3x_3 &+ x_4  &- 2x_5& \\
\end{align*}

Subject to 
\begin{align*}
                       & x_1 &+ 3x_2 &       &+x_4   &+ x_5 &= 2  \\
                       & x_1 &+ 2x_2 &       &- 3x_4 &+ x_5 &= 2  \\
-                      &x_1  &- 4x_2 & +x_3  &       &     &= 1  \\
\end{align*}

with $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5 \geq 0$

There should be Phase I and then Phase II of the simplex method.

---

#### **Q1** - how to explain why Phase I is required here

#### **Q2** - how to know which rows should have artificial variables added

---

For question 1, the objective function can be written as

\begin{align*}
   -z  + 2x_1 + 3x_2 + 3x_3 + x_4  - 2x_5 = 0\\
\end{align*}

The way that the system is initially set up has basic variables  $x_3$ and
non-basic variables $x_1,x_2,x_4,x_5 = 0$.

Meaning the objective function is

\begin{align*}
   -z    + 3x_3 = 0\\
\end{align*}

Or

\begin{align*}
   z    = 3x_3 
\end{align*}

Why is this an issue?

For Question 2 I'm not sure what to consider.

Comment: 1. You need 3 basic variables to start; 2. Your starting point does not satisfy the constraints. 3. Is there no nonnegativity constraint?

Comment: @LinAlg **(1)** why do I need three variables to start (because that's the dimension of the row-space and solution?) **(2)** what do you mean? That my starting point is $x_3 = 1$, and if all other $x_i=0$ the second (and first) equalities (constraints) are false **(3)** There is - I'll add that

Comment: 1. since you have 3 constraints; 2. 'are false': that is not ok. You need basic feasible solutions in every iterate (so basic AND feasible; you have neither)

Answer (score 1):

Point (2) in OP's comment is very near to the an answer.

For each of the first two constraints, there's *no* decision variable

- which has *nonzero* coefficient, and
- which *doesn't* appear in the other two rows.

For a concrete counterexample, you may consider the third row, in which $x_3$

- has coefficient one
- *doesn't* appear in the first two constraints.

Therefore, in general, the first two rows need artificial coefficients.

Remarks: Observe that $\begin{vmatrix} 1 & 3 & 0 \\ 1 & 2 & 0 \\ -1 & -4 & 1 \end{vmatrix} \ne 0$ and $\begin{vmatrix} 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & -3 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \end{vmatrix} \ne 0$, so you may actually *solve it as in [linear-algebra](/questions/tagged/linear-algebra) in exams/tests* so save the trouble of doing phase I.  However, finding initial BFS like this is *never* a general method.